RabbitMq publish message causes channel drain
I try to send a message in NodeJS project using amqplib library. It works until the buffer length is about 8MB (8,388,608)
So in case the message is approx. over 8MB, when I call
this.channel.publish(exchangeName, queueName, buffer, ...

it always returns false and drain event is called after while on the channel.
However, the message limit in default RabbitMQ should be much higher. We did not change anything there.
We use
amqplib "0.10.3
node 20.11.0
RabbitMQ 3.12.10
Erlang 25.3.2.8
tested in linux docker and windows. The behavior is the same.
When I check the amqplib/lib/connection.js, it probably fails when calling
writeResult = buffer.write(bodyFrame);

What am I doing wrong? Is there any settings I am missing?
Any help would be appreciated. I have spent hours with the issue, I am not able to move forward.
